# Performance Testing of SFTP server using jMeter

Tags: ssh, plugins, jmeter, sftp, jmx

I need to perform testing of certain scenarios of upload/download on SFTP server. For that i am using apache JMeter plugin SSH protocol support. I am able to test single file upload for a single user. I am struggling to perform scenarios such as Multiple file upload for single user OR Multiple file upload for multiple users using this plugin.
Any idea if there is any other plugin in order to achieve this or any alternative way?

Custom sampler code

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;

def jsch = new JSch()
def session = jsch.getSession(${__property(loginUserName)}, ${__property(hostURL)}, ${__property(port)}) 
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.setPassword(${__property(loginUserPassword)})
def sftpSession = session.connect()
def channel = session.openChannel("sftp")
channel.connect();
def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
log.info("SFTP Connection with host is acquired" + channelSftp)
channelSftp.cd(${__property(sftpDestinationFolder)});
for(i = 0; i <100; i++){
    def f1 = new File(${__property(inputFileLocationOfBigFile)});
    channelSftp.put(new java.io.FileInputStream(f1), f1.getName()+i);
}
session.disconnect()
```

Working fine on GUI mode of apache server but when running on the linux box or headless way it gives the below error.

```
2020-03-18 03:25:28,918 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class JSch 
 @ line 4, column 12.
   def jsch = new JSch()
              ^

Script1.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class ChannelSftp 
 @ line 12, column 19.
   def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
                     ^

2 errors

javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class JSch 
 @ line 4, column 12.
   def jsch = new JSch()
              ^

Script1.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class ChannelSftp 
 @ line 12, column 19.
   def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
                     ^

2 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:183) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:215) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class JSch 
 @ line 4, column 12.
   def jsch = new JSch()
              ^

Script1.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class ChannelSftp 
 @ line 12, column 19.
   def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
                     ^

2 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:211) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getScriptClass(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:331) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:181) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    ... 6 more
2020-03-18 03:25:28,927 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2020-03-18 03:25:28,927 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
```

Any help on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass more than one file at a time over single SFTP connection, multiple files need to be queued up.

You can however open several connections by a single user or with different users, just make sure to properly parameterize the credentials and file names/locations.

For example:

- Credentials can be parameterized using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- Files can be parameterized using [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, just one question - If i upload multiple files using 'Directory Listing Config' for a single user and pass them as source in SSH SFTP protocol plugin , will every file upload create different session for that user on sftp server or files will get uploaded in one session?

Comment: For this [SSH SFTP plugin](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-sftp) a new connection is created each time the sampler is being called. Check out [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter/) article for more details. If you need to re-use a single session for multiple file transfers - you either need to patch the plugin or come up with your own implementation of the SSH connectivity and SFTP file transfer

Comment: Yes, Thank you @Dmitri T, I will try to create my own sampler.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, i wrote my custom sampler and it works from GUI but when i try to run the same jmx file from the bin directory of apache jmeter server on a linux box using command `sh jmeter.sh -n -t ../../JMX\ Test\ Files/Custom\ sampler\ code\ for\ multiple\ files\ single\ user.jmx -l log.jtl` it gives error as shown in the question.